# jqGrid - Conditionally update/change column name in jqGrid table

Tags: jqgrid

Is there a way to change/update a column name in jqGrid? I need to insert a highlighted text in the column header on change of a drop down field. The drop down field is outside of the jqGrid.

Appreciate any inputs!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the column label with this code.

```
if(condition_for_label_change)
{
     $('#list').jqGrid('setLabel', 'column_index', 'New_Label', { 'text-align': 'left' });
}
```

Assuming your column model looks like this:

```
  $('#list').jqGrid({
.............

    colModel: [
    ..............
    { name: 'column_index', index: 'column_index', align: 'left'},
    ...........
    ]
          .....
);
```

Answer (score 2):

try this..

loadComplete: function () {
    var $grid = $(this), columnNames, name,
        userdata = $grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'userData');

```
if (userdata) {
    if (userdata.title) {
        $grid.jqGrid('setCaption', userdata.title);
    }
    if (userdata.columnNames) {
        columnNames = userdata.columnNames;
        for (name in columnNames) {
            if (columnNames.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                $grid.jqGrid('setLabel', name, columnNames[name]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}